# React Native never[] array map returns null How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, array-map

I created an empty state array than push data in it from firebase.

```
const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
```

When I use `console.log(chats)` function, it returns me the array correctly

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function GetChats() {
      const data = chats;
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "chat"));
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        });
        setChats(data);
      });
    }
    GetChats();
  }, []);
console.log(chats)
```

Console:

1. *`[{…}]`*

   1. **`0`**`:`

      1. **`data`**`: {cinsiyet: 'erkek', memleket: 'rize', name: 'kutay akgün'}`
      2. **`id`**`: "Kutay"`
      3. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   2. **`1`**`:`

      1. **`data`**`: {memleket: 'Rize', name: 'Ali Aydın', cinsiyet: 'Erkek'}`
      2. **`id`**`: "Ali"`
      3. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   3. **`2`**`:`

      1. **`data`**`: {cinsiyet: 'Kadın', name: 'Fatma Aydın', memleket: 'Rize'}`
      2. **`id`**`: "Fatma"`
      3. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   4. **`3`**`:`

      1. **`data`**`: {cinsiyet: 'Erkek', memleket: 'Rize', name: 'Kutay Aydın'}`
      2. **`id`**`: "Kutay"`
      3. `[[Prototype]]: Object`
   5. **`length`**`: 4`
   6. `[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`

**NO PROBLEM UP TO THIS POINT**

But than when I try to render array to a component with map function it returns noting. I use `return` too but it doesn't work.

```
 return (
    
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView>
      {
          chats.map((chat) => {
            return (
            
              <Text key={chat.id}>{chat.data.name}</Text>
            );
          })
          
      
     }
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

chats array type was never[]. To fix it I add one data manually to define type of the array

```
const [chats, setChats] = useState([{id: "Kutay",data:{cinsiyet: "erkek", memleket: "rize", name: "kutay akgün"}}]);
```

now this is how it is:

```
const chats: {
    id: string;
    data: {
        cinsiyet: string;
        memleket: string;
        name: string;
    };
}[]
```

which is true at all.

But now when I try to render array. It only renders the first element which I added manually.

How can I make possible to render other elements too.??

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Hao Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10289265/hao-wu)'s comment solved the problem:

> It didn't update because the reference of `chats` never changed. Pushing element into it won't trigger rerender, even with calling `setChats(data)` which ultimately is itself. A quick fix is to set it as a new reference when setting chats: `setChats([ ...data ]);`